# Why doesn't TypeScript complain about interface violations resulting from Object.create?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype-chain

```
type Foo = {
  x: number;
};

function g(): Foo {
  return {}; // Fails type-check

  // Property 'x' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Foo'.
}

function f(): Foo {
  return Object.create({}); // Passes!
}

function h(): Foo {
  return Object.create({x: 0}); // Also passes
}

function j(): Foo {
  return Object.create({x: "Hi"}); // Also passes!
}
```

Why do `f` and `j` pass type-checking? Is it possible to configure TypeScript so that `h` passes type-checking but `f` and `j` fail?

Comment: `Object.create` returns `any` and is not a generic function. So that's why `any` suits `Foo`

Comment: Is it not intended to use `Object.create` when writing TypeScript code?

Comment: Most likely yes, not intended if you wish to stay on a `typed` side.

Comment: My understanding is that `Object.create` is how you are supposed to create an object with a desired prototype -- everywhere I look says that changing an object's prototype after creation is not a good idea. So is it not intended to write TypeScript code making explicit use of the JS prototype chain?

Comment: `Object.create()` returns `any`. You could create a declaration file that declared a generic overload `create<T>(value: T): T` that would infer the type from `value` and throw the appropriate error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.create` is designed to return `any` by Typescript.
There has been an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3865) in Typescript's Github repository but it's closed and they do not intend to change it soon.